# TcpListener Pending method returns wrong values

Tags: c#

I have the following code in my server side:

```
// Bind to a specific local port number (SERVER_PORT) and any local IP address.
m_tlServer = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Any, SERVER_PORT);

// Start listening for connection attempts.
m_tlServer.Start();

// Start accepting new clients.
// Sleep until a new client(s) will try to connect to the server.
while (!m_bStopThread)
{
    if (!m_tlServer.Pending())
    {
        // Sleep and try again.
        Thread.Sleep(LISTENING_SLEEP_TIME);
        continue;
    }
    else
    {
        // Accept a new client in a new thread. 
        Thread newthread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(HandleNewConnection)); 
        newthread.Start();
    }
}
```

My problem is that when a client tries to connect to the server, the method `Pending` returns `true` several times (usually 4 times) and several thread are created.
I tried to replace that while loop by a loop that uses the `AcceptTcpClient` method (without knowing if there are any connection attempts) and it's works fine. So, I think the problem is caused by `Pending` method.
Can anyone help me? Thanks, Ofer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `AcceptTcpClient` not `Pending` and it will work.

Why what you're doing is producing theses steps :

1. Listener thread see Pending == true
2. Start accept thread
3. Listener thread see Pending == true
4. Start accept thread
5. Listener thread see Pending == true
6. Start accept thread
7. **First accept thread begin to run**
8. Listener thread see Pending == false

In a nutshell that's not because you start a thread that some random instruction inside is executed immediately. The point of the thread is exactly that : It will execute later.

If you want to have a way to stop the listening process use `WaitHandles` :

```
// In your class somewhere stopEvent is a ManualResetEvent

while(true)
{

    var asyncResult = listener.BeginAcceptTcpClient(null, null);

    var waitHandles = new [] { stopEvent, asyncResult.AsyncWaitHandle };

    var waitResult = WaitHandle.WaitAny(waitHandles);

    if (waitResult == 0) return;

    var client = EndAcceptTcpClient(asyncResult);
    // Create thread to speak with this client

}
```

Your method that want to stop the thread will just need to `stopEvent.Set()`

Comment: @Fuex : Factually true, but pooling is a bad idea and should be avoided at all cost. We don't need more badly programmed software hogging the processors of our computers. There is an efficient, faster, easier alternative why use a worse solution ?

Comment: @Fuex to be able to terminate the 'accept' you can also use the callback and check some `m_stop`variable at start, but what the framework does in this case is basically execute the code that I wrote in a ThreadPool thread and call your callback. In a simple case like this the result is the same. But real async IO is much more powerful as the same thread could be waiting for new client, waiting for new packets to arrive on all the clients and waiting for paquets to be sent... (Then you run javascript instead of C# and call it node.js)

Comment: There should be a badge for "speaking with ghosts"